# Ctrl+V does not work in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, copy-paste, intellij-14

A while ago, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> stopped working in Intellij IDEA. Neither the shortcut nor `Edit` > `Paste` works. It's really weird, since "Paste Simple" still works fine, so does <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

I've seen a lot of suggestions to solve this problem, but most of them are somehow related to the Vim Emulator for IntelliJ, which I don't use. I tried to play around with the Keymap, but could not get it to work.

I'm using Intellij 2017.2.5 on Windows 10. Maybe I screwed it up myself somehow, but I wish to fix it, because it's really painful to work without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: Backup first then try deleting setting folder: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

Comment: Worked! I deleted the config folder. I'll have to reinstall some plugins, but it's worh it. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can try alternatives:

> Ctrl + Shift + V for Windows or Linux

or

> You might try **Ctrl+INS** for copy and **Shift+INS** for paste and
>   see if they work. They are the traditional cut and paste and have been
>   around a lot longer than Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v

Comment: already tired Ctrl+INS. When pressing Ctrl + Shift + V, "Pasting from History" comes up, where I can select previously copied text, but if I click the paste button, still nothing happens ./

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I regularly reboot so I always have a back-up of my settings. When I reimported them and updated the plugins I could paste again without issues.
Back-up your settings from a working state File>>Manage IDE Settings>>Export Settings and use >> >>Import Settings to apply them.

If you don't have a back-up you can try it, but you might be backing up the problem as well. In that case you will have to reset to defaults and reset the IDE to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows WebStorm 2023.1.1 I had the same issue, I made MENU > FILE > repair IDE it didn't fix it till I made a clear cache and restart that fixed it

BTW while i had the issue Win+V worked

Answer (score -1):

My OS is Ubuntu 18.04, and i had this problem before. An effective solution for my IDE is to set the Keymap to Default, which is file>setting>Keymap.